# 100 GiB Files upload to AWS Ec2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-transfer, awss3transfermanager

We have the n number of files with total size of around 100 GiB. We need to upload all the files to EC2 Linux instance which is hosted in AWS (US region).
My office(in India) internet connection is 4Mbps dedicated leased line. Its taking more than 45 min to upload 500 MB file to EC2 instance. which is too slow.

How do we transfer this kind of bulk upload with minimum time period..?
If it is 100s of TB we can go with snowball import and export but this is 100 GiB.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 3x faster than you experience.

If there are many small files you can try to "zip" them to send fewer large files.

And make sure you dont bottleneck the linux server by encrypting the data (ssh/sftp). Ftp may be your fastest way.

But 100GB will always take at least 57 hours with your max speed..

Comment: Aslund, Thanks for your suggestion.